# What to pass into file I/O method as Context argument?

Tags: java, android

Feeling really stupid, and somehow I have a feeling I'm supposed to pass "this" as the argument for "Context", but honestly this whole concept is new to me and as confused as it has me  I'd rather know 100% what and why before I start my endless hunt of syntactical errors.

I had asked a question a few days ago about how to use a file input/output stream to write the contents of an ArrayList of class objects to file to be retrieved when the app starts.  Basically, I wanted to save entered values.  I was feeling pretty confident in my code until I realized I have to pass a Context when calling my save and retrieval  methods.  It was then the realization I had no idea what a context was hit me... So yeah.

These are my methods:
Create the file (I guess?):

```
private static void updatePickThreeList(Context mC){
     FileOutputStream stream = null;

     try{
         stream=mC.openFileOutput(PICK_THREE_NUMBERS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         ObjectOutputStream dout = new ObjectOutputStream(stream);
         dout.writeObject(pickThreeNumbers);
         stream.getFD().sync();
         stream.close();
         dout.flush();

     }catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Retrieve the data (I hope):

```
              private static void getPickThreeList(Context mC){
     FileInputStream stream = null;
     try{
         stream=mC.openFileInput(PICK_THREE_NUMBERS);
         ObjectInputStream din  = new ObjectInputStream(stream);
         pickThreeNumbers = (ArrayList<PickThreeNumbers>) din.readObject();
         stream.getFD().sync();
         stream.close();
         din.close();

     }catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }catch(ClassNotFoundException e1){
         e1.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

And I assume I can call the first method to save the ArrayList to file, then call the second method to simply load the saved values to the array.  By the way, the arrays and other values used are:

```
static List<PickThreeNumbers> pickThreeNumbers = new ArrayList();
final static String PICK_THREE_NUMBERS="pick_three_numbers";
```

So, per the response to my original question, both of these methods are required to be passed in a context, and Java is being fairly adamant about getting that context (go figure), so when I call updatePickThreeList(Context);, what exactly goes in as the "Context"?

Thanks in advance - I'm one very appreciative programming noob.

Comment: Just nitpicking :), I think `flush()` should happen before you `close()` the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so when I call updatePickThreeList(Context);, what exactly goes in as the "Context"?

An instance of some class that extends `Context`. Depending on where you are calling this code, that might be an `Activity` or a `Service`.

BTW, please be careful when using static data members, so you do not introduce memory leaks.

Also, please do disk I/O on a background thread (e.g., `AsyncTask` or `IntentService`).

Comment: Do you receive notifications when someone mentions `Context` on SO? ;-)

Comment: @PaulBurke: Fortunately, no, otherwise spammers would use that hole in my defenses... :-)

Comment: So... I should pass in "this" as to point to the activity class where the list is stored?  Also, what do you mean a "background thread"? Sorry, I'm fairly new at all this...

Comment: @NicolasMustaro: "I should pass in "this" as to point to the activity class where the list is stored?" -- if `this` is an instance of some subclass of `Context`, sure. You are showing the *implementations* of these methods in your question, not where and how you are trying to *call* them. Hence, I have no idea what `this` is. "Also, what do you mean a "background thread"?" -- um, threads have been around for at least a couple of decades. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)

Comment: @CommonsWare I know what a thread is, just didnt know exactly what you meant by a "background" thread.  I suppose just a thread running independently of the current activity, eh?  Basically these two methods are inside the activity's class, and I am trying to call them from within the same class from "onCreate" and "onDestroy".  Basically, save it when the "onDestroy" is called (app closes) and load it in onCreate (when app opens).

Comment: @NicolasMustaro: "I suppose just a thread running independently of the current activity, eh?" -- each process has a main application thread that drives the UI. Any other thread is a background thread. "Basically these two methods are inside the activity's class" -- then `this` is the `Activity`, and since `Activity` inherits from `Context`, you can use `this` as the parameter to your methods. "Basically, save it when the "onDestroy" is called (app closes) and load it in onCreate (when app opens)" -- app != activity, except maybe for single-activity apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare:  What I mean to say is when the main activity closes... It's basically a single-activity application, everything being in the main activity and other activities are only for data input (only get called via startActivityForResult).  Thanks for all your information, I appretiate it a lot!